# What's the difference between an object initializer and a constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, object-initializer

What are the differences between the two and when would you use an "object initializer" over a "constructor" and vice-versa?  I'm working with C#, if that matters.  Also, is the object initializer method specific to C# or .NET?

Answer (score 266, accepted):

Object Initializers were something added to C# 3, in order to simplify construction of objects when you're using an object.

Constructors run, given 0 or more parameters, and are used to create and initialize an object *before* the calling method gets the handle to the created object.  For example:

```cs
MyObject myObjectInstance = new MyObject(param1, param2);
```

In this case, the constructor of `MyObject` will be run with the values `param1` and `param2`. These are both used to create the new `MyObject` in memory.  The created object (which is setup using those parameters) gets returned, and set to `myObjectInstance`.

In general, it's considered good practice to have a constructor require the parameters needed in order to completely setup an object, so that it's impossible to create an object in an invalid state.

However, there are often "extra" properties that could be set, but are not required.  This could be handled through overloaded constructors, but leads to having lots of constructors that aren't necessarily useful in the majority of circumstances.

This leads to object initializers - An Object Initializer lets you set properties or fields on your object *after* it's been constructed, but *before* you can use it by anything else.  For example:

```cs
MyObject myObjectInstance = new MyObject(param1, param2)
{
    MyProperty = someUsefulValue
};
```

This will behave about the same as if you do this:

```cs
MyObject myObjectInstance = new MyObject(param1, param2);
myObjectInstance.MyProperty = someUsefulValue;
```

However, in *multi-threaded* environments the atomicity of the object initializer may be beneficial, since it prevents the object from being in a not-fully initialized state (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12842511/2822719) for more details) - it's either null or initialized like you intended.

Also, object initializers are simpler to read (especially when you set multiple values), so they give you the same benefit as many overloads on the constructor, without the need to have many overloads complicating the API for that class.

Comment: I agree, but would like to add that debugging object initializer can be painful, especially if you have nested structure, since object initializer is considered one line of code (nicely formatted), just like my sentence.

Comment: @Reed-Copsey very good explanation, will there any performance gains with object initializers or is it only for readability?

Comment: @Mahender Actually, there are typically (very, very small) performance losses when using object initializers.  Constructors can be written to be more efficient.

Comment: Your answer is nice but **your example is incorrect**.
Please update your code based on @nawfal 's answer. Your answer has so many upvotes that noone will look another and that will make a lot of people have the wrong understanding of how an object initializer works

Comment: I don't see how you have to define a lot of overloaded constructors to handle non required properties. Optional parameters in the constructor should be fine, this is not java.

Comment: You'll have to weigh code readability against correctness of the code. Parameters in constructors force you to set all variables. If you forget to set one variable, the compiler will complain. If you forget a variable when using an initializer list, you won't notice it until run-time (and maybe not even immediately). Furthermore: the field can't be readonly, making accidental changes possible, without the compiler complaining

Comment: @bgusach Though it is possible to use optional parameters in a constructor, Code Analysis rule [CA1026: Default parameters should not be used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1026-default-parameters-should-not-be-used) warns that this is not a considered a good practice. (For a *public* or *protected* constructor or method, that is. Code Analysis will not raise this warning for a *private* constructor or method.)

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse Fields and properties **can** be `readonly`.

Answer (score 53):

A constructor is a defined method on a type which takes a specified number of parameters and is used to create and initialize an object.

An object initializer is code that runs on an object after a constructor and can be used to succinctly set any number of fields on the object to specified values.  The setting of these fields occurs **after** the constructor is called.

You would use a constructor without the help of an object initializer if the constructor sufficiently set the initial state of the object.  An object initializer however must be used in conjunction with a constructor.  The syntax requires the explicit or implicit use (VB.Net and C#) of a constructor to create the initial object.  You would use an object initializer when the constructor does not sufficiently initialize the object to your use and a few simple field and/or property sets would.

Comment: Might be good to add that it's the default constructor that's called when an object initializer is invoked, just for lucidity

Comment: I just fixed a nasty null ref issue, because someone thought it's not after.

Comment: @AbrahamPhilip this is not necessarily the case. You can also use parameterized constructors AND an object initializer at the same time.

Comment: Whoops, you're absolutely right, thanks @nepp95!

Answer (score 37):

When you do

```
Person p = new Person { Name = "a", Age = 23 };
```

this is what an object initializer essentially does:

```
Person tmp = new Person(); //creates temp object calling default constructor
tmp.Name = "a";
tmp.Age = 23;
p = tmp;
```

Now this facilitates behaviour like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16209150/661933). Knowing how object initializers work is important.

Comment: can it just be Person p = new Person {Name = "a"}?

Comment: @nick-s yes, very much. This is what object initializer is for. You initialize members you want.

Comment: I didn't know constructor paranthesis could be skipped. Thanks.

Comment: @AnarKhalilov not only that, I find it distinctly more elegant without the parentheses. May be it conveys the point a little more poorly though [the parentheses tells the constructor has been called].

Answer (score 20):

If you have properties that MUST be set on your object for it to work properly, one way is to expose just a single constructor which requires those mandatory properties as parameters.

In that case, you cannot create your object without specifying those mandatory properties. Something like that cannot be enforced by object initializers.

Object initializers are really just a "syntax convenience" to shorten initial assignments. Nice, but not really very functionally relevant.

Marc

Comment: Another way to ensure that essential properties are set on an object at construction time is to provide a static ("factory") method on a class that returns a constructed object. That factory method constructs the object via a *private* constructor. (Defining multiple private constructors may be useful.)

Comment: ...Also, it is sometimes useful to create a static factory *class* that has the responsibility for constructing instances of one or more other classes. For example see [File.Create Method (String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_IO_File_Create_System_String_) (and its overloads) which creates a `FileStream` object.

Answer (score 4):

A constructor is a method (possibly) accepting parameters and returning a new instance of a class. It may contain initialization logic.
Below you can see an example of a constructor.

```
public class Foo
{
    private SomeClass s;
    public Foo(string s)
    {
       s = new SomeClass(s);
    }
}
```

Now consider the following example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public SomeClass s { get; set; }
    public Foo() {}
}
```

You could achieve the same result as in the first example using an object initializer, assuming that you can access SomeClass, with the following code:

```
new Foo() { s = new SomeClass(someString) }
```

As you can see, an object initializer allows you to specify values for public fields and public (settable) properties at the same time construction is performed, and that's especially useful when the constructor doesn't supply any overload initializing certain fields.
Please mind, however that object initializers are just syntactic sugar and that after compilation won't really differ from a sequence of assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Object initializers can be useful to initialize some small collection which can be used for testing purposes in the initial program creation stage. The code example is below:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<OrderLine> ordersLines = new List<OrderLine>()
            {
                new OrderLine {Platform = "AmazonUK", OrderId = "200-2255555-3000012", ItemTitle = "Test product 1"},
                new OrderLine {Platform = "AmazonUK", OrderId = "200-2255555-3000013", ItemTitle = "Test product 2"},
                new OrderLine {Platform  = "AmazonUK", OrderId = "200-2255555-3000013", ItemTitle = "Test product 3"}
            };
        }
    }
    class OrderLine
    {
        public string Platform { get; set; }
        public string OrderId { get; set; }
        public string ItemTitle { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the catch. In the above code example isn’t included any constructor and it works correctly, but if some constructor with parameters will be included in the OrderLine class as example:

```
public OrderLine(string platform, string orderId, string itemTitle)
{
   Platform = platform;
   OrderId = orderId;
   ItemTitle = itemTitle;
}
```

The compiler will show error - There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter…. It can be fixed by including in the OrderLine class explicit default constructor without parameters:

```
public OrderLine() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now, years later, I am reconsidering the use of Constructors over Object Initializers.  I have always liked Object initializers, as they are quick and easy.  Pick which fields you want to set, and set them and you are done.

But then along came along the `nullable context` wherein you must specify which properties are nullable, and which are not.  If you ignore using a constructor, and instead use an object initializer, the compiler is not going to be assured that your object is in fact whole (no null properties which should in fact be non-null) But a properly written and used constructor resolves all of that.

But an even better solution is to use the "required" keyword on the fields that are expected to be populated on creation, whether through a constructor, or an object Initializer.  It's a new keyword of C# 11, which comes with .net 7

Answer (score 0):

Object initializers are especially useful in LINQ query expressions. Query expressions make frequent use of anonymous types, which can only be initialized by using an object initializer, as shown in the code example below:`

```
var orderLineReceiver = new { ReceiverName = "Name Surname", ReceiverAddress = "Some address" };
```

More about it - [Object and collection initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)