# Set minimum window size in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am having trouble setting the minimum size of my window in a C# application I am working on.  I have tried this code in the form's constructor:

```
this.MinimumSize.Width = 800;
this.MinimumSize.Height = 600;
```

But the compiler says:

> Cannot modify the return value of
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control.MinimumSize' because it is not a variable

Can anybody shed some light on this issue for me?

EDIT:

Using:

```
this.MinimumSize = new Size(800,600);
```

Gives:

```
 error CS0118: 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.Size' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'
```

Sorry I forgot to mention that I had already tried that.
Also forgot to mention that I am not using Visual Studio.

Comment: Size is a `struct` and you have to create a new `struct`.

Comment: Consult your favorite C# language book about the difference between value and reference types.  The Size type is a struct, a value type.

Comment: Interesting: with Mono I get a much more helpful [error CS1612](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747654/cannot-modify-the-return-value-error-c): Cannot modify a value type return value of ‘System.Windows.Forms.Form.MinimumSize’. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Since `Size` is a struct, you can't do that.
Instead, you need to assign a new `Size` value to the property, like this:

```
this.MinimumSize = new Size(800, 600);
```

**EDIT** Your compiler is wrong; it's confusing the `Size` class with the `Control.Size` property.

To work around this unjust error, you need to qualify the type with a namespace:

```
this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 600);
```

Or you just forgot `using System.Drawing`.

Comment: system.drawing... why the hell should I need that just to set a damn window size???  Thanks

Comment: @Dai: Because Windows Forms need to be drawn. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx

Answer (score 6):

You should use something like this:

`this.MinimumSize = new Size(100, 100);`

`Width` and `Height` are used to get the existing values instead of setting them.

If you go to the definition of `MinimumSize`, you will see this:

`public override Size MinimumSize { get; set; }`

Once again confirming that even when you decide to set the value for it, you have to pass an actual `Size` instance. `Width` and `Height` are properties strictly tied to the `Size` instance.

Comment: That's not actually true; the properties are writable.

Comment: Properties are writable for the Size instance (when you are passing it to MinimumSize).

Answer (score 4):

This is the compiler error:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wydkhw2c(VS.71).aspx

The basic problem is that the MinimumSize member property returns a struct - which is a value type - and so is copied into a local temporary variable - and this prevents you from writing a value back to the underlying property.

To get around this, you need to assign to MinimumSize itself:

```
this.MinimumSize = new Size(800, 600);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign directly to the `MinimumSize` property:

```
this.MinimumSize = new Size(800, 600);
```

Basically, the return value of the `MinimumSize` property is always a *new* struct object; the compiler doesn't let you assign to this temporary value (as stated in the error, it's not a variable).

[This MSDN Social thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/a0394c6c-da63-486f-b198-5047eecff413) is most enlightening about the subject.