# How to may explorer.exe appear on top of ever form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code and it opens the my documents accordingly. but the problem is it is below my application i want it above my main form

```
     String path = @"C:\Users\Diether\Documents";
     System.Diagnostics.Process prc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
     prc.StartInfo.FileName = path;
     prc.Start();
```

Comment: I'm surprised it appears below your application.  Does it do that even if not running under a debugger?   You could always just minimise your application after launching Explorer, if that would be better.

Comment: Off-topic, but get the documents folder using: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)`

Comment: It may happen if `TopMost` property of the main form is set to `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use StartInfo, maybe this helps you: `prc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;` you have to insert it before the `prc.Start();`-line.

OR

you minimize your window when you open the explorer:
[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314041/set-minimum-window-size-in-c-sharp-net)