# Persisting a control property to the Designer.cs file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, designer

I have a custom control which contains a property of type `PointF`. When this control is added to a form and is saved, the designer.cs file doesn't say something like:

```cs
...
this.customControl.LocationF = new System.Drawing.PointF(50.0f, 50.0f);
...
```

Instead, it says this:

```cs
...
this.customControl.LocationF = ((System.Drawing.PointF)(resources.GetObject("customControl.LocationF")));
...
```

I've been trying to "persuade" this property to properly serialise to the designer file, and my search has turned up a couple of promising leads:

- [DesignerSerializerAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.designerserializerattribute.aspx), but I can't make sense of exactly what it's supposed to do, or how to use it.
- A [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) which can convert to an [InstanceDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.instancedescriptor.aspx) (looking at the example given by MSDN for [Generating Code for Custom Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973818.aspx#custcodegen_topic4)).

I've followed the example given in the MSDN example, replacing `Point` with `PointF` and `int` with `float`, then my CustomControl looks like this:

```cs
public class CustomControl : Button
{ 
  [Category("Layout")]
  [TypeConverter(typeof(PointFConverter))]
  public PointF LocationF
  {
    get { return this.Location; }
    set { this.Location = new Point((int)value.X, (int)value.Y); }
  }
}
```

As far as I can see, this should work, but it seems to have no effect on how it's serialised to the designer file.

Something else I've just noticed - the `PointFConverter` isn't actually ever used when generating the designer.cs file - it's only used when reading or writing the value of the property in the properties box in design mode... Maybe this `TypeConverter` thing is a dead end...

## In Short...

How do I make a control's property (specifically in this case a `PointF` type) serialise correctly to a form's designer.cs file?

## Update

I'm now looking at a subclass of the [CodeDomSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.codedomserializer.aspx), which does change the designer.cs code (adding a comment as per the example on that page works) but it seems that I can only apply it to the CustomControl class as a whole, and try to modify the base serialization to replace the `CodeCastExpression` with a `CodeObjectCreateExpression`. This seems like a really messy way of doing things, though...

Comment: You need to get the TypeConverter added to the Type not the Property of that type for the Designer to use it for serialization. Look add the TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes overloads to get your TypeConverterAttribute(and therefore you Converter) added to PointF.

Comment: @Ralf That certainly seems to work. Just one other question - at present, I've put the `AddAttributes` call in the CustomControl's static constructor. Could you recommend anywhere more suitable to keep it so that it would apply to any other controls with `PointF` properties? Putting it in the `PointFConverter` constructor (static or instance) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Ralf Ok, no worries - if you want to put your comment as an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: Put your call to [TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.addattributes(v=vs.110).aspx) in the static constructor of your `PointFConverter` class. I just did this (for a `RectangleFConverter` class) and, finally, WinForms Designer stopped writing out my `RectangleF` values as binary in the `.resx` file, and wrote them out as `new System.Drawing.RectangleF(...)` in my Designer file!

Answer (score 0):

Create the following class:

```
public class MyPointF
{
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }
}
```

Use the following class definition for your `CustomControl`:

```
public class CustomButton : Button
{
    private MyPointF _locationF = new MyPointF() { X = 50, Y = 50 };

    [Category("Layout")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public MyPointF LocationF
    {
        get
        {
            return _locationF;
        }
        set
        {
            _locationF = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Sources:

- [How to: Serialize Collections of Standard Types with the DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171833.aspx)
- [Cannot modify the return value error c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747654/cannot-modify-the-return-value-error-c-sharp).