# Move simple Object in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to move a simple `Object` in Unity but I get the following error message:

`cannot modify the return value of unityengine.transform.position because itar is not variable`

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class walk : MonoBehaviour {
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        float movespeed = 0.0f;
        movespeed++;
        transform.position.x  = transform.position.x + movespeed;

    }
}
```

Comment: It appears the X property of position is not mutable, can you assign a new Position value instead? 
eg `transform.position = new Position(transform.position.x + movespeed, transfrom.position.y);`

Comment: Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Position' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (Assembly-CSharp)

Comment: All such questions should use `unity3d` tag. The tag `unity` is for a completely different thing. Please learn the tags before using them.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't assign the `x` value on `position` directly as it's a value type returned from a property getter. (See: [Cannot modify the return value error c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1747654/1269654))

Instead, you need to assign a new `Vector3` value:

```
transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + movespeed, transform.position.y);
```

Or if you're keeping most of the coordinate values the same, you can use the `Translate` method instead to move relatively:

```
transform.Translate(movespeed, 0, 0)
```

Comment: it is work ok , but there are another problem , because the object is Directly Disappear after i press Play Game .

Comment: @Nawaf your computer is too fast! Multiply your movespeed by `Time.deltaTime` to keep it uniform on all CPU speeds.

Answer (score 2):

A slight improvement over Chris' answer:

```
transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x + movespeed * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y);
```

`Time.deltaTime` the amount of time it's been between your two frames - This multiplication means no matter how fast or slow the player's computer is, the speed will be the same.