# c# how do I do a private set property?

Tags: c#

I am creating a `VECTOR` object like so, but I am initializing it in the constructor:

```
public VECTOR position { get; private set; }
```

I am doing this operation:

```
position.x += 2;
```

`VECTOR` has a variable x defined as:

```
public double x { get; set; }
```

I get the error when I do the `+=2` operation that says:

> Cannot modify the return value of 'Projectile.position' because it is
>   not a variable

I want to be able to modify the position vector in the current class, and I want it to be accessible but not modifiable in other classes.

Comment: Please put the class for Vector.

Comment: I'm guessing Vector is a struct.  Make it a class.

Comment: `x` isn't a variable, it's a property. Also, you haven't really given enough information. You should consider posting your definition of `VECTOR`. Finally, all caps in a class name goes against standard C# naming conventions. `Vector` would be expected by most C# developers, as would `Position`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: A quick google on the error message gave me [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747654/cannot-modify-the-return-value-error-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your problem is with the `Vector` class actually being a `struct`. Assume you have the following declarations:

```
public class Projectile
{
    public VECTOR position { get; private set; }        

    public Projectile()
    {
        position = new VECTOR();
    }
}

public struct VECTOR 
{
    public double x {get; set;} 
}
```

You cant edit properties of the `position` property directly because you are accessing a copy of that field (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1747702/1300049)).

If you don`t want to convert your VECTOR into a class you can add a method that updates the position of your projectile:

```
public void UpdatePosition(double newX)
{       
    var newPosition = position;
    newPosition.x = newX;

    position = newPosition;
}
```

That will create a copy of the position, then update its x property and override the stored position. And the usage would be similar to this:

```
p.UpdatePosition(p.position.x + 2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Expose the X property (and others) of VECTOR in a class.

```
public class myObject {
private VECTOR position;
public double X { get{return position.x;}set{position.x=value;}}
}
```

Usage example:
    myObject.X += 2;

Comment: But isn't the set method public then?

Comment: This protects position but allows for X to be set. Suppose I misunderstood what needs to remain protected.