# Is there a difference between ref T indexer and a get/set indexer?

Tags: c#, ref, c#-7.0

I've tried both of the following codes and they both seem to work the same way.

```
// Case 1:  ref T indexer
class Map {
    Tile[,] tiles;

    public ref Tile this[int x, int y]
        => ref tiles[x, y];
}

// Case 2:  get/set indexer
class Map {
    Tile[,] tiles;

    public Tile this[int x, int y] {
        get => tiles[x, y];
        set => tiles[x, y] = value;
    }
}
```

Assume that `tiles` is initialized in the constructor, and that `Tile` is a `struct`. Is there any notable difference between the two? What if `Tile` was a `class`?

Comment: There is a difference only when the type is mutable

Comment: Yes, big difference.  Give Tile an X property and try map[0,0].X = 42;

Comment: Oh I see. Case 2 won't allow you to modify its properties. Thanks, I'll go with the former then. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Assume that tiles is initialized in the constructor, and that Tile is a struct. Is there any notable difference between the two?

**CASE 1**

```
// Case 1:  ref T indexer
class Map {
    Tile[,] tiles;

    public ref Tile this[int x, int y]
        => ref tiles[x, y];
}
```

You are returning a `ref` to the indexed `Title` object so you will be able to modify it and even set it to a different object. This is a new feature of C# 7.0 (as you have tagged) wherein it allows to return a `ref` and then you can store it as well. In other words **it returns the storage location not the value**.

Since you are returning the storage location you can totally assign a new `Tile` object to the indexed item. Without the `ref` you will only be able to modify it.

**CASE 2**

```
class Map {
    Tile[,] tiles;

    public Tile this[int x, int y] {
        get => tiles[x, y];
        set => tiles[x, y] = value;
    }
}
```

Here is the same but without C# 7.0 for brevity:

```
class Case2MapWithoutCSharp7
{
    Tile[,] tiles;

    public Tile this[int x, int y]
    {
        get { return tiles[x, y]; }
        set { tiles[x, y] = value; }
    }
}
```

Since `Tile` is a `struct`, when you index it you will get a copy and if you try this (assuming `Tile` has a property `X`):

```
 map[0, 0].X = 10;
```

> Error CS1612  Cannot modify the return value of 'Case2MapWithoutCSharp7.this[int, int]' because it is not a variable.

The compiler is throwing that error to be explicitly clear that what you think you are doing (modifying the indexed item), is not really what you are doing. You are actually modifying the copy so it forces you to do exactly that. So, to be able to set the `X`, you will need to do it on the copy like this:

```
var tile = map[0, 0];
tile.X = 10;
```

You can read more on that error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747654/cannot-modify-the-return-value-error-c-sharp).

> What if Tile was a `class`?

In the first case, since you are returning the storage location you can totally assign a new `Tile` object to the indexed item.

In the second case, without the `ref`, since `class` objects are passed by reference, you will be able to modify it but not set the reference to a whole new object. So you can do this:

```
map[0, 0].X = 2;
```

But if you did this:

```
var tile = map[0, 0];
tile = new Tile();
tile.X = 5;
```

You are obviously mutating a brand new `Tile` and not the one you indexed.