# CS1612 Cannot modify the return vaue because it is not a variable

Tags: c#

```
private void CmdPositionRel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
CmdTest.Location = new Point(
    CmdTest.Location.X = + 20, CmdTest.Location.Y);
```

What I am trying to achive is that by pressing the button CmdPosition the button CmdTest goes 20 pixels in the positive direction of X.

According to the bock I am learning from this code is right...

Problem : CS1612 Cannot modify the return value of control.Location because it is not a variable

In all the other threads the answer was to add "new Point". I have that but still the problem appears.

Sorry I am a complete beginner, in programming and on StackOverflow. Hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: isn't this the same as other problems

Comment: Welcome to stack Overflow. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) are some useful links on how to complete a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Typo, it is just + not =+

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot modify the return value error c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747654/cannot-modify-the-return-value-error-c-sharp)

Comment: First law of _Coding Club_....the computer is always right.  Well usually... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to make assignment to `CmdTest.Location`.  check my fix

```
CmdTest.Location = new Point(
    CmdTest.Location.X + 20, CmdTest.Location.Y);
```

Comment: Considering OP is probably new to programming, maybe expand upon _"make assignment to CmdTest.Location"_.   i.e. mention the `=` sign; where it can and can't be used.  Otherwise the difference is subtle