# Change Object's X axis Scale Only

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I change an object's X axis scale over time? I tried this code:

```
transform.localScale.x *= 1.1f;
```

But it gives me this error:

> Cannot modify the return Value of "Transform.localScale" because it is not a variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot modify the return value error c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747654/cannot-modify-the-return-value-error-c-sharp)

Comment: @NotsoVeteran I've read the answer but how can I apply that in my case?

Comment: See my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change just a single value in localScale, you'll need to create a new Vector3 locally. Two examples of doing this:

```cs
// Make a new vector with identical y and z values, but with a new x value.
var newScale = new Vector3(
    transform.localScale.x * 1.1f,
    transform.localScale.y,
    transform.localScale.z);

// Set scale to the new Vector3.
transform.localScale = newScale;
```

An alternative:

```cs
// Copy into a variable. We can now make per-value changes.
var newScale = transform.localScale;
newScale.x *= 1.1f;

// Copy back into the transform.
transform.localScale = newScale;
```