# 2 ways to create new object by setting property values

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are C# 3.0 object initializer constructor parentheses optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661025/why-are-c-3-0-object-initializer-constructor-parentheses-optional)

Hi all
I have a class `Question` which has a property `Text`

```
public class Question
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to create an object of this type by giving value to property.
I can do that in this two ways:

`Question q = new Question { Text = "Some question" };`

and

`Question q = new Question() { Text = "Some question" };`

Is there any difference between this two cases and if they are the same, why we need both?
Thanks.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661025/

Comment: @Nathan, you are right. Questions are same.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's absolutely no difference between the two examples.

In this case, and in this case alone, the `()` on the constructor is optional.

Comment: @Samvel - The code will compile to the same IL, but the compiler can infer the brackets in this case.

Comment: But is it possible to assign new values to properties like that? For example, `Customer cust = _context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == 1); cust{ Name = "NewName"} //error` I usually do it like this `cust.Name = "NewName"`. Just wondering if I could use same syntax as the above to  update the properties

Comment: @HaikalNashuha no, that's not possible with the current syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Use `()` in case if you require to pass argument to the constructor.

Else it will not create any difference...

They both are important as in case if you add any constructor in Question Class then you need to pass args, that is possible using `()`.