# Difference between class initializers in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, class, object, instantiation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are C# 3.0 object initializer constructor parentheses optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661025/why-are-c-3-0-object-initializer-constructor-parentheses-optional)

What is the difference between instatiating an object by using

`classInstance = new Class() { prop1 = "", prop2 = "" };`

and

`classInstance = new Class { prop1 = "", prop2 = "" };`

Comment: do you need a new keyword in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing. The second is just a short-cut for the first. The first allows you to include arguments to a constructor. So, you can't use the short-cut if the class doesn't have an empty constructor.

You may have an interest in this question:

[Why are C# 3.0 object initializer constructor parentheses optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661025/why-are-c-3-0-object-initializer-constructor-parentheses-optional)

And Eric Lippert´s great blog post:

[Ambiguous Optional Parentheses, Part One](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/20/ambiguous-optional-parentheses.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: Nothing. The `()` can be used if you want to pass in some constructor args but 
in your case since you don't have any, you can skip `()`.

For eg. `()` is useful here.

```
  Foo foo = new Foo(someBar){Prop1 = "value1", Prop2 = value2};
```

but if you are trying to call the parameter-less constructor, it's optional

```
  Foo foo = new Foo {Prop1 = "value1", Prop2 = value2};
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference other than syntax, you are still calling the parameter-less constructor either way.