# C# Initializer list - when to use () operator after class name?

Tags: c#, initializer-list

Sometimes an initializer list is specified after the class name without using the () operator:

```
Cat cat = new Cat { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" }
```

Other times it is specified after the () operator:

```
List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>
    {
        new Cat(){ Name = "Sylvester", Age=8 }
    }
```

I am assuming the difference is because here new Cat() is inside the list. But I still don't understand why it should be different. So why the difference, and when to use which syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are C# 3.0 object initializer constructor parentheses optional?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661025/why-are-c-sharp-3-0-object-initializer-constructor-parentheses-optional)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the initializer list you can omit the (), when using a parameterless constructor. It does not matter with the new Cat() is inside the list or not.

Answer (score 6):

You must specify the `()` when there is no default (parameterless) constructor - when you have to supply parameters.

When a class has default constructor (or a parameterless one), you can always omit the `()` when using an initializer. The compiler does the magic for you and you can think of things as - the compiler inserts them for you.

Comment: If there is no default constructor () wouldn't work no? The example I gave above is from MSDN, and there the Cat class doesn't have any constructors, meaning there is a default one.

Comment: This answer is wrong as it is currently. You can not always omit the (). "new Cat;" would not work. You can omit it when you use the initializer list.

Comment: @YechielLabunskiy - No, it wouldn't work. The default constructor is the one generated when you _don't_ specify a constructor and it is a parameterless one.

Comment: @user1908061 - In the context of the question (object initializers), you can always omit it.

Comment: @Oded So you are saying there is no specific reason Cat() is called inside the list in my example but w/o () when outside the list? Meaning - both ways are acceptable here since Cat has no constructor defined (meaning there is a default one defined by the compiler)

Comment: @YechielLabunskiy - Yes, that's what I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difference to which of the two you decide to use. Compare these two `Cat` instances:

```
var catA = new Cat();   // traditional constructor
catA.Name = "Mittens";  // set property

var catB = new Cat { Name = "Not Mittens" }; // all in one initializer
```

They are identical in functionality, just a shortcut notation. The first way is the traditional way, which most *object-oriented* (OO) languages create objects using the *constructor*.  C# recently has added this new method of creating objects and setting properties to make code cleaner.

Even if your class does not have a parameterless constructor (`new()`), you can use the `{...}` initialization still.

Consider this:

```
var dogA = new Dog("Fido");
var dogA.Age = 12;

var dogB = new Dog("Not Fido") { Age = 7 };
```

Even if parameters are required in the *constructor*, you can still use this style of initialization as long as you supply them.

Comment: They're not entirely identically and there's a difference. Read http://haacked.com/archive/2013/01/11/hidden-pitfalls-with-object-initializers.aspx for further information. :)