# Difference Between object initializations in c#

Tags: c#

Just wanted to know if there is any difference between the two object initialization??

Which one should I be using??

with and without parenthesis ()

```
var data = new Apple()
{
 Color = "red", 
 Taste = "good"
}
```

AND

```
var data = new Apple
{
Color = "red", 
Taste = "good"
}
```

Comment: Here comes the storm of absolutely identical answers

Comment: @DamonGant Are you a wizard?

Comment: All you'll ever want to know about this (and more) can be found [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3661197/2779990

Answer (score 7):

When you use the second form, in fact it's compiled as the first form. The second form means you want to use the *parameterless* constructor. Be careful with that because if your class doesn't have any *parameterless constructor* you can't use it, of course the first form can't also be used.

Comment: +1, for parameterless constructor, definitely a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference at all. They both will call parameterless constructor.

They are both transformed into:

```
var data = new Apple();
data.Color = "red";
data.Taste = "good";
```

by compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Parameterless constructors are used to save you from the default errors, for example suppose if you have parameterized constructor:

```
public Apple(string color, string taste)
{
data.Color = "red";
data.Taste = "good";
}
```

sometime you/user may forget to pass the parameter for constructor Apple(x,y). So it is always a good practice to define a parameterless constructor inside the class like:

```
public Apple()
{
data.Color = "yellow";
data.Taste = "sour";
}
```

if you forgot to call the constructor with desired parameters value than the default parameterless constructor will be called and the variables will be initialized to default.

Comment: If your class has reasonable defaults it's a good practice to provide a parameterless constructor.  But that's a long way from it *always* being a good practice.  There are many cases where you shouldn't have a parameterless constructor, so I'd be wary about recommending it as "always good".