# what is the difference between new Object{} and new Object(){}

Tags: c#

I define objects from class in C# this way

```
var something = new SomeThing()
{
    Property = "SomeProperty"
}
```

and this way

```
var something = new SomeThing
{
    Property = "SomeProperty"
}
```

what is the difference between these definitions?

Comment: No difference whatsoever.

Comment: R# would recommend removing unnecessary parenthesis.

Comment: @NagarajS Completely different question.

Comment: @Rotem True, the other one is about anonymous types. In this case, the actual type is specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing, when the parentheses are empty.

They only make sense when you provide a parameter; you can do that at the same time:

```
var something = new SomeThing("some other value")
{
    Property = "SomeProperty"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Nothing. The `()` is redundant. The only thing required is that the object has a default constructor.

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference as such. Parentheses are optional when using a function as a constructor (with the `new` operator and no parameters). Parentheses are always required when calling a function when you do not use the new operator.

Answer (score 3):

You can omit the parentheses, the default constructor will be used (assuming one is available).

When using object initializers, you only need to use parentheses if you want to specify a different constructor.

Eric Lippert's take on why the parentheses were made optional: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3661197

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. You can omit the empty braces in this case. For the compiler, those two are 100% equivalent.