# Is there any subtle difference between inline initializing a list with or without '()'?

Tags: c#, list, initialization

E.g. is there any technical difference between invoking:

```
List<string> list = new List<T> () { "one", "two", "tree" };  // with ()
```

and

```
List<string> list = new List<T> { "one", "two", "tree" };    // without ()
```

?

The result is obviously the same. But I am interested if there is any technical difference in the way of invocation or this is only a convenience .NET C# shortcut.

Comment: No difference, Empty Argument is totally needless in this case

Comment: @Pankaj: that it's needless is not an indication whether it is _required_ or not.

Comment: Related and informative: [Why are object initializer constructor parentheses optional?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661025/why-are-c-sharp-3-0-object-initializer-constructor-parentheses-optional)

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference. The parenthesis are not required when using a collection initializer with the default constructor. However, if you want to use another constructor you cannot omit the parenthesis.

Some code refactoring tools like ReSharper will indicate this by showing the parenthesis as redundant.

Collection initializers are not limited to "built-in" .NET types. A type implementing `IEnumerable` and providing a suitable `Add` method can use a collection initializer.

Answer (score 1):

Both will actualy compile into

```
List<string> list;
List<string> temp;
temp = new List<string>();
temp.Add("one");
temp.Add("two");    
temp.Add("tree");
list = temp;
```

if you check generated IL code.

Comment: Collection initializer version create initialize temp list and then set reference to actual variable. IL's for both are not same.

Comment: @RohitVats Yes collection initializer creates temporary local variable, but for both versions: with parentheses and without parentheses IL is same. Corrected code to better represent generated IL.