# The difference between new List() {...} and new List {...}

Tags: c#, list

When initializing a new List in C#, both of following will compile:

(1) `List<string> s = new List<string>() { "value" };`

and

(2) `List<string> s = new List<string> { "value" };`

What is the difference between case 1 and case 2?

Comment: There is none. It's just that the `()` is optional for that declaration. (Resharper warns about the redundant `()`.)

Comment: See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661025/why-are-c-sharp-3-0-object-initializer-constructor-parentheses-optional) (which talks about object initializers, which are in the same ball park), which links to [Ambiguous Optional Parentheses, Part One](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/20/ambiguous-optional-parentheses.aspx). Eric Lippert's blogs explain very well the "why" rationale behind language design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rings true for any type. Generally, you specify the `()` if you need to pass something to the types constructor that it doesn't expose for setting publically. If there's no parameters needed, the `()` are just fluff.

Consider the scenario that you may want to do some additional validation/logic to a property and you don't allow direct manipulation of it:

```
public class Foo
{
    private string Bar { get; set; }

    public string FooBar { get; set; }

    public Foo (string bar)
    {
        Bar = bar + "foo";
    }
}
```

So this is allowed:

```
var foo = new Foo("bar")
{
    FooBar = "foobar"
};
```

Yet this isn't:

```
var foo = new Foo
{
    Bar = "bar",
    FooBar = "foobar"
};
```

There are some C# types that only allow you to set certain properties within the constructor.

Comment: You might specify that the parentheses remain mandatory if you don't initialise properties inside the Field Initializer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. It will be translated as:

```
List<string> s1 = new List<string>();
s1.Add("value");
List<string> s2 = new List<string>();
s2.Add("value");
```

Answer (score 1):

From 7.6.10.1 Object creation expressions of the [C# reference 5.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029):

> An object creation expression can omit the constructor argument list and enclosing parentheses provided it includes an object initializer or collection initializer. Omitting the constructor argument list and enclosing parentheses is equivalent to specifying an empty argument list.

Comment: I have merged my response (adding the link) to yours

Comment: Thanks xanatos, I had trouble finding a section number.

Answer (score 0):

The latter is called Object Initialization. You may also use `MyClass m = new MyClass { MyVar = 3 };`

Comment: *The latter is used the Field Initializer* ? What? [Field Initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645759%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: It's not called Field Initialization. It's called a collection initializer. The alternative you give is called an object initializer. Field initializers are the default values you give for fields in a class declaration.

Comment: @Rawling Indeed, I´ve changed this.