# Difference between new ClassName and new ClassName() in entity framewrok query

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, class, model-view-controller

I trying to get some values from database by using entity framework

i have a doubt about

> Difference between `new ClassName` and `new ClassName()` in entity framewrok query

### Code 1

```
 dbContext.StatusTypes.Select(s => new StatusTypeModel() { StatusTypeId = 
 s.StatusTypeId, StatusTypeName = s.StatusTypeName }).ToList();
```

### Code 2

```
dbContext.StatusTypes.Select(s => new StatusTypeModel { StatusTypeId =    
  s.StatusTypeId, StatusTypeName = s.StatusTypeName }).ToList();
```

You can see the changes from where i create a `new StatusTypeModel` and `new StatusTypeModel()` object.

> - **The both queries are working for me. but i don't know the differences between of code 1 and code 2 .**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661025/why-are-c-sharp-3-0-object-initializer-constructor-parentheses-optional

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with EF. This is a C# language feature. When you declare properties of a class using `{ ... }` you don't need to tell that the empty constructor of a class shall be called. Example:

```
new StatusTypeModel() { StatusTypeId = s.StatusTypeId, ... }
```

is exactly the same like this:

```
new StatusTypeModel { StatusTypeId = s.StatusTypeId, ... }
```

There is no difference in performance. The generated IL (intermediate language) is identical.

However, if you don't declare properties you must call the constructor like this:

```
var x = new StatusTypeModel(); // brackets are mandatory
x.StatusTypeId = s.StatusTypeId;
...
```