# Declaring a new instance of class with or without parentheses

Tags: c#

I'm writing a small example to practice creating new instances of a class.

I have the following code:

```
class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
}

class MainClass
{
   static void Main()
   {
      var p = new Person
      {
         Name = "Harry",
         Age = 20
      };
      Console.WriteLine($"Name: {p.Name}. Age: {p.Age}");

      p = new Person()
      {
         Name = "Hermonie",
         Age = 18
      };
      Console.WriteLine($"Name: {p.Name}. Age: {p.Age}");

      Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

It's working.

My question: What's the difference between

```
var p = new Person {};
```

and

```
var p = new Person() {};
```

Which version should I use?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661025/why-are-c-sharp-3-0-object-initializer-constructor-parentheses-optional

Comment: Normally one would omit the `()` part, if you are using the default constructor.

Comment: Off Topic: I know Hermione is academically brilliant and all, is there anywhere in the books that shows she's been put ahead a year, as alluded by the ages in the question? :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe Magic. haha :)

Comment: @HappyCoding Actually re-reading them on and off at the moment as my main memories of the story are the films now - _so_ much more in the books (as always).  Don't recall anything specific about ages either way, would have to go and look :)

Comment: Keep in mind that she's also gained a bit of age, relative to her friends, due to her use of the time turner.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both will call the default parameter-less constructor. So I believe both are same.

Comment: They most definitely are the same :)

Comment: I'm guessing the OP really meant to ask about the non-default initialisation. But that would be the same too, of course.

Comment: Resharpper recommend remove () so I think they are same

Answer (score 5):

In this case there is no difference, they both call the default constructor. The difference would be obvious if there was another constructor with parameters:

```
var o = new Person { ... };
var p = new Person("John") { ... };
```

The empty parentheses are only needed when you don't use the initialization:

```
var p = new Person(); // Works
var o = new Person; // Error
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you wanted to initialize the property values, using the standard:

```
Person p = new Person();
```

Should suffice, but they are the same thing in your case and call the default constructor.

But, if you wanted to set the property values, you can do the following:

```
Person p = new Person { Name = "Harry", Age = 18 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a p by using the default constructor:

```
var p = new Person();
```

Declare a p by using a constructor that takes name as a parameter:

```
var p = new Person("Harry");
```

Declare a p by using an object initialiser:

```
var p = new Person {Name="Harry"};
```

See [What's the difference between an object initializer and a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740658/whats-the-difference-between-an-object-initializer-and-a-constructor) and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx