# Create Dictionary with custom class for value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm using a dictionary in C# and want to make the value a custom class.  I have the following code.

```
public class myMovies
        {
           public string Name { get; set; }
           public string Year { get; set; }
        }
        Dictionary<string, myMovies> file_dict = new Dictionary<string, myMovies>();

        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path1, "*.mkv", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            file_dict.Add(file, new myMovies("x", "x");
        }
```

[image]

I'm doing something wrong, I just have no idea at this point.  As a side note, this code does work when I just use a <string,string> dictionary and just store a text value in the value pair.

Edit
Required a constructor in my class definition.  Thanks for help.

Comment: you can reduce the question to: how create a new instance of myMovies class.

Comment: @SirRufo, add that as an answer and I'll mark it.  I just needed the correct search.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719077/declaring-a-new-instance-of-class-with-or-without-parentheses

Comment: The my Movies class doesn't have a constructor with two string arguments. Your IDE should tell you that, this code doesn't build and I don't believe there's no error reported somewhere (unless you're using notepad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either provide an appropriate constructor in the class definition:

```
public class myMovies
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }

    public myMovies(string name, string year)
    {
        Name = name;
        Year = year;
    }
}
```

Or use [object initializer syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) to assign the property values when instantiating the object:

```
        file_dict.Add(file, new myMovies { Name = "x", Year = "x" });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you it expects a Constructor, so give it what it expects:

```
public class myMovies
{
    public myMovies(string name, string year)
    {
         Name = name;
         Year = year;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```