# Difference between Object() and Object{}

Tags: c#, oop, object, constructor

C# will allow to create an object using either Object() or Object{}. What is the difference with Object() and Object{}

```
public item getitem()
{

return new item()

}

public item getitem()
{

return new item {}

}
```

Comment: See: [What's the difference between an object initializer and a constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740658/whats-the-difference-between-an-object-initializer-and-a-constructor?rq=1)

Comment: I got it already but now I know from Jon skeet that Object{} calling parameter less constructor implicitly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This syntax:

```
new SomeType{}
```

is an [*object initializer expression*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) which happens to set no properties. It calls the parameterless constructor implicitly. You can add property assignments within the braces:

```
new SomeType { Name = "Jon" }
```

This syntax:

```
new SomeType()
```

is *just* a call to the parameterless constructor, with no opportunities to set properties.

Note that you can *explicitly* call a constructor (paramterized or not) with an object initializer too:

```
// Explicit parameterless constructor call
new SomeType() { Name = "Jon" }

// Call to constructor with parameters
new SomeType("Jon") { Age = 36 }
```

See section 7.6.10.2 of the C# 4 specification for more details about object initializers.

I would highly recommend that if you *aren't* setting any properties, you just use `new SomeType()` for clarity. It's odd to use an object initializer without setting any properties.

Comment: Could you please explain your last point?  What would the constructors look like for these two examples?

Comment: @Peter: There'd be one constructor without parameters and one constructor with a string parameter. They'd be perfectly normal constructors. The type itself doesn't need to know anything about whether object initializers are being used.

Answer (score 6):

`item()` calls default constructor, whereas `item {}` calls default constructor and allows to use (empty in this case) [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`new item {}` uses an [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx).  In your example, there is no difference, but normally you would just call `new item()` if you don't wish to actually utilize the object initializer.