# from the outside reach the class properties

Tags: c#, oop

```
public class Departman
{    
    Person _p = new Person();

    public Person p
    {
        get { return _p; }
        set { _p = value; }
    }    
}

public class Person
{
    private string _PersonName;

    public string PersonName
    {
        get { return _PersonName; }
        set { _PersonName = value; }
    }
}
```

From the outside I can reach the Person name like this

```
Departman dp = new Departman();
dp.p.PersonName;
```

However, I cant reach like this:

```
Departman dp = new Departman { p.PersonName };
```

What can I do to reach both way PersonName.

Comment: `Departman dp = new Departman { p.PersonName };`? What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Calling a public property `.p` is a *really* bad idea; why not call that `.Person` ?

Comment: right, what should be this ?

new Departman { p.PersonName };

Comment: Also, *person* has a *name*, that's why the class is called `Person` and the property is called `Name`. To me, `Person.Name` makes much more sense than `Person.PersonName`.

Comment: It is juast a sample code Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are looking to initialize person's name, you can do this:

```
Departman dp = new Departman { p = new Person { PersonName = "Joe" } };
```

The `PersonName` property is nested inside the `Departman`'s `Person` object, so you need to nest initializers as well. You can also expose `PersonName` directly, like this:

```
public class Departman {
    Person _p = new Person();
    public Person p {
        get { return _p; }
        set { _p = value; }
    }
    public string PersonName {
        get { return _p.PersonName; }
        set { _p = value.PersonName; }
    }
}
```

This makes the following possible:

```
Departman dp = new Departman { PersonName = "Joe" };
```

Comment: Do I need initialize Person again,it is already initialize inside the departman class? like thsi,Departman dp = new Departman { p = new Person { PersonName = "Joe" } };

Comment: @user2460637 If you want to use the curly brace syntax, but do not want to expose `PersonName` separately, then the answer is "yes".

Comment: does it means "curly brace" is not actually initializer??only initialize primitive type?

Comment: @user2460637 Curly brace by itself is not an initializer; it lets you initialize properties only as part of a `new` expression. Inside curly braces you can omit `new ...` when it can be deduced from the context (see Marc's answer for that) but the braces in the initializer are part of a `new` expression.

Answer (score 3):

> Departman dp = new Departman { p.PersonName };

This syntax has no sense.
When you create a new object followed with { }, it is an initializer. This is useful to inject a value to a property so you could do :

new Departman { p = new Person { PersonName = "Foo Bar" } }

Comment: what if,I initialize person class inside the constructure of departman?

Comment: Do I need initialize  Person again,it is already initialize inside the departman class?

Comment: Initializers act like if you write :
Departman obj = new Departman();
obj.Person = new Person();
Therefore, the value you specify in the initializer will overwrite what you set in the constructor.
See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740658/whats-the-difference-between-an-object-initializer-and-a-constructor).

By the way, you should either decide to use initializer or constructor for a property but not both as it would be quite unreadable and difficult to maintain over time.

Comment: so create an instance of  Person _p = new Person(); inside departman,redundacy for my example, right?

Comment: If you set the "p" property inside an initializer, you don't have to set it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are initializing `p` in the constructor, you don't need a `new Person` - you only need to set the `p.PersonName`, which would be:

```
Departman dp = new Departman { p = { PersonName = "Marc" } };
```

However! A property called `p` is a really bad idea - and having a `PersonName` on a `Person` seems rather redundant; IMO that should be:

```
var dp = new Departman { Person = { Name = "Marc" } };
```

Actually, you don't even need a `set` on the `p` / `Person` property, since this approach doesn't use it:

```
public class Departman {
    private readonly Person person = new Person();
    public Person Person { get { return person; } }
}
public class Person {
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: You say `new Departman { p = { PersonName = "Marc" } }` -- does that really modify the existing (constructor-created) instance, or does it create a new one?  I thought the latter (or am I misreading your first sentence?).

Comment: could u explain more,whats wrong this sentax? Departman dp = new Departman { p = { PersonName = "Marc" } };

Comment: Do I need initialize Person again,it is already initialize inside the departman class?