# How can I use Console.Write in object initializer?

Tags: c#, .net, object-initializers

When I use `Console.Write` in object initializer I get this error

> Error CS0747  Invalid initializer member declarator

```
person[i] = new Karmand()
            {
                Console.Write("first name:"),
                FirstName = Console.ReadLine(),
                LastName = Console.ReadLine(),
                ID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()),
                Hoghoogh = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())
            };
```

Comment: @MostafizurRahman Why is that relevant?

Comment: Why should that be possible in the first place? `Console.Write()` doesn't even return a value. What would allowing that there achieve?

Answer (score 7):

**You can't** because `Console.Write` is not an accessible property or field of `Karmand`. You can only set values of class properties and fields in [object initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

Your code is a syntactic sugar ([a little bit different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/740658/3970411)) for the code below.

```
var person[i] = new Karmand();
// what do you expect to do with Console.Write here?
person[i].FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
person[i].LastName = Console.ReadLine();
person[i].ID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
person[i].Hoghoogh = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

You can have a constructor inside `Karmand` class to print that for you if you want.

```
public class Karmand
{
    public Karmand(bool printFirstName = false)
    {
        if (printFirstName)
            Console.Write("first name:");
    }

    // rest of class code
}
```

and then use it like

```
person[i] = new Karmand(printFirstName: true)
            {
                FirstName = Console.ReadLine(),
                LastName = Console.ReadLine(),
                ID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()),
                Hoghoogh = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `Console.Write("first name:")`. `Console.Writeline` is not an assignment to a property or a field.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384261.aspx)

> An object initializer is used to assign values to properties or
>   fields. Any expression which is not an assignment to a property or
>   field is a compile-time error.
>
> To correct this error Ensure that all
>   expressions in the initializer are assignments to properties or fields
>   of the type.

**Update:**
If you need to use Console.Writeline, then use it before the object initializer like

```
Console.Writeline("first name:");
{ person[i] = new Karmand()
            {
                FirstName = Console.ReadLine(),
                LastName = Console.ReadLine(),
                ID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()),
                Hoghoogh = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())
            };
```