# how to use Console.ReadLine() inside object initializer in C#

Tags: c#

```
//using object initializers
namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Employee
    {
        public string firstName;
        public string lastName;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Employee obj = new Employee()
            { 
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your first name");
            firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your last name");
            lastName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Your full name is " + firstName + " " + lastName);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use Console.Write in object initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018595/how-can-i-use-console-write-in-object-initializer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You don't.

You do all that before initializing your object

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your first name");
var firstName - Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter your last name");
var lastName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Your full name is " + firstName + " " + lastName);

Employee obj = new Employee()
{ 
    firstName = firstName,
    lastName = lastName
 }
 Console.ReadKey();
```