# Select an object by id linq to xml C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I'm begginer in linq to xml. i Have an **xml** file, i want to read it, and **select** object(bicycle) by **Id**.
My test xml file is:

```
<Bikes>
<!--- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -A new Bike- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
    <Bike Id="1">
      <Big_Picture>Image</Big_Picture>
      <Small_Picture>Image</Small_Picture>
      <Emblem_Picture>Image</Emblem_Picture>
      <Firm>Image</Firm>
      <Model>Image</Model>
      <Price>Image</Price>
      <Colour>Image</Colour>
      <Frame_Size>Image</Frame_Size>
      <Description>Image</Description>
      <Gears>Image</Gears>
      <Groupset>Image</Groupset>
      <Brakes>Image</Brakes>
      <Frame_Material>Image</Frame_Material>
      <Wheel>Image</Wheel>
    </Bike>
</Bikes>
```

I want to select this bike by **id (1)**, then put the elements of this bike in object of my **class (Bike)**. How can i do that? My code, of course, doesn't perform the task:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Bikes.xml");
xdoc.Descendants("Bike").Select(p => new {
        id = p.Attribute("Id").Value,
        picture = p.Element("Small_Picture").Value,
        model = p.Element("Model").Value,
        price = p.Element("Price").Value
    }).ToList().ForEach(p => {
        Bike bike = new Bike(p.id, p.picture, p.model, p.price);//Constructor
        bikes_xml.Add(bike);
    });
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: I'm sorry, incorrectly expressed

Comment: Whats the issue? What is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve one bike as in your question then use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var data = XDocument.Load("data.xml")
                    .Descendants("Bike")
                    .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Attribute("Id").Value == "1");
if(data != null)
{
    Bike bike = new Bike(data.Attribute("Id").Value,
                         data.Element("Small_Picture").Value,
                         data.Element("Model").Value,
                         data.Element("Price").Value);
}
```

If you want to construct it in the linq syntax then:

```
Bike x = (from bike in XDocument.Load("data").Descendants("Bike")
          select new Bike(bike.Attribute("Id").Value, 
                          bike.Element("Small_Picture").Value, 
                          bike.Element("Model").Value, 
                          bike.Element("Price").Value))
         .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == 1);
```

*And as @Selman Genç recommended, see if you can change to use [Object Initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) instead of the constructor with the parameters. For more about it check [What's the difference between an object initializer and a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/740658/6400526)*

Comment: Thanks, the first variant is what i need.

Comment: @Eldar - You are welcome :) Consider the object initializer vs. the constructor tip :)

Answer (score 1):

If by *doesn't work* you mean you are getting all the items, all you need is a `Where`:

```
var bikes =  xdoc.Descendants("Bike")
                 .Where(e => (int)e.Attribute("Id") == 1)
                 .Select(p => new
                 {
                     id = p.Attribute("Id").Value,
                     picture = p.Element("Small_Picture").Value,
                     model = p.Element("Model").Value,
                     price = p.Element("Price").Value
                 }).ToList();
```

You can change your class to use properties if you aren't using them already, so you don't need to create an anonymous type. You can just use `new Bike { ... }`