# merge items in list from distinct value

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following model:

```
class serverMaster
{
    public string vm { get; set; }
    public string bm { get; set; }
    public string incrday { get; set; }
    public string incrtime { get; set; }
    public string fullday { get; set; }
    public string fulltime { get; set; }
    public string backupgroup { get; set; }
    public serverMaster(string vm1, string bm1, string incrday1, string incrtime1, string fullday1, string fulltime1, string backupgroup1)
    {
        vm = vm1;
        bm = bm1;
        incrday = incrday1;
        incrtime = incrtime1;
        fullday = fullday1;
        fulltime = fulltime1;
        backupgroup = backupgroup1;

    }
}
```

and I have a data set like this:

[image]

How can I use Linq to find duplicates in the first column (so for example merge Aether) and concatenate the other fields.

I would ideally like to see output like this:

[image]

Comment: I guess you  need to have a look at the MoreLinq package which has the .distinct function

Comment: I think linq has distinct too

Comment: .distinctBy was what I meant. I'm sorry, it was a typo

Comment: You could also have a look at [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11121/merging-ienumerable-and-removing-duplicates). looks like you have landed in a similar situation

Comment: I should add that I'm trying to merge from a single list, not two lists.

Comment: Is it an in memory collection or to some database? If so EF? or what? In addition what are the names of the fields from the picture you added?

Comment: It need not be necessarily two lists to group them or perform union function. You could try it on your instance of serverMaster

Comment: It's a memory collection. I'm reading from text files and storing to a LIST: List<serverMaster> allItems = new List<serverMaster>();

Fields are named: Server Name, Backup Type, Incremental Day, Incremental Time, Full Backup Day, Full Backup Time, Backupgroup

In that order ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to `GroupBy` on the key field (by your comment and model I'm assuming it is `vm` and then to perform an aggregation operation for the other fields. From your sample data you want to concatenate the strings:

```
var result = allItems.GroupBy(item => item.vm)
                     .Select(group => new serverMaster {
                         vm = group.Key,
                         incrday = string.Join(", ", group.Select(i => i.incrday)),
                         incrtime = string.Join(", ", group.Select(i => i.incrtime)),
                         fullday = string.Join(", ", group.Select(i => i.fullday)),
                         fulltime = string.Join(", ", group.Select(i => i.fulltime)),
                         backupgroup = string.Join(", ", group.Select(i => i.backupgroup))
                     }).ToList();
```

---

As you do not have a default constructor you should:

```
var result = allItems.GroupBy(item => item.vm)
                     .Select(group => new serverMaster (
                         group.Key,
                         string.Join(", ", group.Select(i => i.incrday)),
                         string.Join(", ", group.Select(i => i.incrtime)),
                         string.Join(", ", group.Select(i => i.fullday)),
                         string.Join(", ", group.Select(i => i.fulltime)),
                         string.Join(", ", group.Select(i => i.backupgroup))
                     )).ToList();
```

You can have a look at: [What's the difference between an object initializer and a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/740658/6400526)

Comment: Looks great, but the code here "group => new serverMaster" is asking that I pass parameters. Do I add them?

Comment: @JoshHilditch - oh true. That is because you do not have a default constructor and instead a constructor that gets all the parameters. I'll update my answer but I recommend to use object initializers instead of the constructor

Comment: "there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'vm1' os serverMaster. That's what I'm getting.

Comment: Oh ok. Sweet :)

Comment: @JoshHilditch - see update + Have a look at naming conventions in C# for the names of the properties

Comment: Well that's done it. Thank you, absolute legend. If I could buy you a beer, I would. That was the final piece of my puzzle which is going to save me so many hours of work. Wish I could +100 for this. Thank you.

Comment: @JoshHilditch - haha :) I wish that sometimes too ;p but the max we can do is mark as solved and upvote :) Glad it helped