# Initializing an array of structs that contain a array of bytes

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, initialization

```
struct a
{
int x;
int y;
byte[] z;
}

var b = new a[] {{0, 0, {0, 0, 0}}, {1,1, {1,1,1}}};
```

I want to initialize an array of a struct each of which contains an array of bytes. I also tried:

```
var b = new a[] {{0, 0, new byte[] {0, 0, 0}}, {1,1, new byte[] {1,1,1}}};
```

Comment: Try `var b = new a[] {new a() {0, 0, new byte[] {0, 0, 0}}, new a() {1,1, new byte[] {1,1,1}}};`

Comment: I tried it, no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constructor will make it more arranged and readable:

```
struct a
{
    int x;
    int y;
    byte[] z;

    public a(int xv, int yv, byte[] zv)
    {
        x = xv;
        y = yv;
        z = zv;
    }
}

public void Initialize()
{
    var b = new a[] {new a(0,0,new byte[] { 0,0,0}),
    new a(1,1,new byte[] { 1,1,2})};
}
```

**Another way According to your Comment**
 
 1. if you declare the access modifier of the struct fields as public you
    will be able to initialize them using [object initializer and not
    with constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740658/whats-the-difference-between-an-object-initializer-and-a-constructor) (constructor is a method).
 2. you can use static class and immediately call that object
 3. make `b` global and public (var is only local keyword) in order to call it 
from outside (i would use a more descriptive name then `b`).

full example:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("y value of index 1 is: {0}", General.b[1].y);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class General
{
    public static a[] b = new a[] { new a() { x = 0, y = 0, z = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0 }},
                                    new a() { x = 1, y = 1, z = new byte[] { 1, 1, 1 }}
        };
    public struct a
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public byte[] z;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm porting code I wrote in C. In C, this struct array is created by the compiler without having to run any code at run time. I know this is probably the best answer, but having to create it at run time just feels a bit awkward.

Comment: @BingBang now your question is a little bit more clear, please see my edits.

Comment: Thanks @jonathana.I'll try it out Monday.

Comment: The actual code contains 64 members in the struct array and each struct member contains a byte array with 256 members. That's why I was hesitant about creating it at run time.

Comment: I get errors that say the elements are inaccessible due to protection level

Comment: @BingBang C# is strongly typed more than C, VB, etc...make sure everything that uses that class is public (see few fixes in my code)

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular constructor with some values, and write the array contents later:

```
public struct A
{
    const int Size = 256;
    // mutable structs are evil. 
    public int x, y;
    // At least make the arrays (not the contents) readonly
    readonly public byte[] a;
    readonly public byte[] b;

    public A(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.a = new byte[Size];
        this.b = new byte[Size];
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new A(48, 64);
        var y = new A(32, 24);

        x.a[4] = 1;
        y.b[127] = 31;
    }
}
```