# Is there Anyway to Declare Object and change there properties While initialization

Tags: c#

I m beginner in learning C#. i Saw some code but i have no idea how it works.
Is there anyway to Change/Give values to the Property of an object at initialization.

For Example: 
i am declaring a Button and want to Change the Button.Name Directly

Button sender = new Button();

But i saw code something like:

```
Button sender = new Button({Name = "button_name"});
```

I am Trying to Shorten the Code From

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Name = "Mybutton";
```

to this:

```
Button btn = new Button({Name = "MyButton";});
```

But i Get syntax Error Here.

Comment: Which version of C# are you working on?

Comment: Object Initializer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer

Comment: working on .NET 4.5

Comment: See also: [Object and Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)

Comment: YEah.. YOur Link Helped in details.. thanks for help..

Comment: You could also check: [What's the difference between an object initializer and a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/740658/5893316)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that your syntax is not correct.  The correct syntax for what you are attempting to do is:

```
Button btn = new Button()
{
    Name = "MyButton"
};
```

If you want to set more than one property during initialisation, use a comma to separate the property values:

```
Button btn = new Button()
{
    Name = "MyButton",
    Text = "Hello"
};
```

This is called an Object Initializer and was introduced in C# 3.0.

Comment: This is what i want. Thanks for Your Help.. Cheers.