# What is it called when an object is initialized without a type?

Tags: c#, language-features

I've only encountered this a handful of times, and I don't understand it entirely yet, but I feel the need to research what's actually going on here behind the scenes.

I recognize that it is creating a new instance of an object, but the type has not been specified.

```
var myObject = new {
    SomeProperty = "ABC",
    SomeOtherProperty = true
};
```

It also works when you swap out `var` for `object` or `dynamic`. However, with that in mind, I can't really find what it's called in order to research it. I believe it is referred to as a `pseudo-class` or `pseudo-object` but I can't find any actual documentation on it.

I've performed several Google searches on the topic ([here's the latest](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20it%20called%20when%20an%20object%20is%20initialized%20without%20specifying%20the%20type%20c%23%3F&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS922US922&oq=what%20is%20it%20called%20when%20an%20object%20is%20initialized%20without%20specifying%20the%20type%20c%23%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57.13651j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)), and even reviewed a few related SO posts ([here's one about initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740658/whats-the-difference-between-an-object-initializer-and-a-constructor)), but I'm still not finding the answer.

---

What is this actually called?

Comment: [It's called an object initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi that's not quite it, as I'm not specifying a type here and the resulting structure isn't defined anywhere but that snippet.

Comment: Ah, okay. Then it's an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types). Wasn't sure your `object` wasn't just a [mre]-replacement for a type you'd defined

Comment: @PranavHosangadi that's a solid point! :D Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its called an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types), and its instantiated directly.

> ## [Instantiation of anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator#instantiation-of-anonymous-types)
>
> To create an instance of an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types), use the new operator and object initializer syntax:
>
> ```
> var example = new { Greeting = "Hello", Name = "World" };
> Console.WriteLine($"{example.Greeting}, {example.Name}!");
> ```