# I cannot initialize the member variable at the new object

Tags: c#

Im pretty new to C# and I hope to get some help here.
The `mypath` variable is a placeholder in this case.
The class is included by `using Programm.src;`

This is my code where I want to initialize my `input_excel_path` variable at the `mainWindow1` object.

The outcome in the compiler

> error CS0747 : Invalid initializer member declarator and  compiler
> error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'name'.

```
        MainWindow mainWindow1 = new MainWindow()
        {
            mainWindow1.m_input_excel_path = mypath;
        };
```

This is my class:

```
   class MainWindow
   {
    
    public string m_input_excel_path = String.Empty;
    
    public MainWindow(string input_excel_path )
    {
        m_input_excel_path  = input_excel_path;       
    }
}
```

Comment: how is `name` from the exception related to the above code? Can't see it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [object initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) syntax specifies the properties directly, without the variable name. You already have a parametrized constructor, so why not call the constructor directly?

```
MainWindow mainWindow1 = new MainWindow(mypath);
```

If you wanted to use the initializer syntax the way you intend, you have to implement a parameterless constructor in your class and then use the correct syntax when initializing:

```
class MainWindow
{
    
    public string m_input_excel_path = String.Empty;
    
    public MainWindow(string input_excel_path)
    {
        m_input_excel_path = input_excel_path;       
    }

    public MainWindow() {
        // empty ctor required for your initializer to work
    }
}

// somewhere else:
MainWindow mainWindow1 = new MainWindow
{
    m_input_excel_path = mypath
};
```

The initializer syntax is simply syntactic sugar for the following code:

```
MainWindow mainWindow1 = new MainWindow();
mainWindow1.m_input_excel_path = mypath;
```

See [What's the difference between an object initializer and a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740658/whats-the-difference-between-an-object-initializer-and-a-constructor) for more details.

And there's nothing preventing you from mixing a constructor call and initializer syntax. E.g. if you had another field/property in your class:

```
class MainWindow
{
    
    public string m_input_excel_path = String.Empty;
    public int age;
    
    public MainWindow(string input_excel_path)
    {
        m_input_excel_path = input_excel_path;       
    }
}

// somewhere else:
MainWindow mainWindow1 = new MainWindow(mypath)
{
    age = 42
};
```

Comment: This really helped me a lot to understand. Thank you :D

Comment: @Hi1mNico I have extended my answer to include more examples and explanations. HTH

Comment: The semicolon after 42 should not be there. Object initializer parameters should be separated by comma.

Comment: @PalleDue Right. Annoying muscle memory :) fixed, thanks